# Java jsoup link extracting(wrong output)

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to get all the links in the `<a class="subHover"` but the thing is that with the code I wrote I get all the links in the page, here is my code:

```
String website = "http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/?start=" +maxPage;
           Document docOne = Jsoup.connect(website).get();
           Elements elem = docOne.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "search-result");
           Elements el = elem.attr("class", "subHover");
           System.out.println(el.select("a[href]"));
```

I dont really know where I am doing it wrong :/
The output of the code is:

```
<a href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/corporate-governance-internal-control-and-compliance-from-an-info_578545.html"> <img class="border" src="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/migration_catalog/Rapporter_och_opinionsmaterial/Rapporters/corporate_governance_10017apdf_579280.html/ALTERNATES/PORTRAIT_170/Corporate_Governance_10017a.pdf"> </a>
<a class="subHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/corporate-governance-internal-control-and-compliance-from-an-info_578545.html"> <h2> Corporate Governance, Internal Control and Compliance - - From an Information Security Perspective</h2> </a>
<a class="noHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/personer/christer-magnusson_538711.html"><span class="entypo entypo-user"></span><span>Christer Magnusson</span></a>
<a href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/from-stagnation-to-acceleration-proposed-guidelines-for-a-europea_595930.html"> <img class="border" src="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/migration_catalog/Rapporter_och_opinionsmaterial/Rapporter/proposed_guidelines_for_a_european_research_policypng_595932.html/ALTERNATES/PORTRAIT_170/Proposed_guidelines_for_a_European_research_policy.png"> </a>
<a class="subHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/from-stagnation-to-acceleration-proposed-guidelines-for-a-europea_595930.html"> <h2>From stagnation to acceleration - Proposed guidelines for a European research policy</h2> </a>
<a class="noHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/medarbetare/emil-gornerup_566685.html"><span class="entypo entypo-user"></span><span>Emil Görnerup</span></a>
<a href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/decision-usefulness-explored-an-investigation-of-capital-market-a_588531.html"> <img class="border" src="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/migration_catalog/decision-usefulness_omslagjpg_588538.html/ALTERNATES/PORTRAIT_170/Decision%20usefulness_omslag.jpg"> </a>
<a class="subHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/decision-usefulness-explored-an-investigation-of-capital-market-a_588531.html"> <h2>Decision usefulness explored - An investigation of capital market actors´ use of financial reports</h2> </a>
<a class="subHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/tax-reductions-and-public-resources_590643.html"> <h2>Tax reductions and public resources</h2> </a>
<a class="noHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/staff/mikael-witterblad_572108.html"><span class="entypo entypo-user"></span><span>Mikael Witterblad</span></a>
<a class="noHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/medarbetare/johan-fall_551949.html"><span class="entypo entypo-user"></span><span>Johan Fall</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your results is, that the document contains HTML like this:

```
<div class="subHover"> 
 <span class="subject">PUBLICATION</span>
 <span class="subject-info"><b>Publicerad:</b> <time datetime="2005-06-30">30 June 2005 </time></span> 
 <div class="result-content clearfix"> 
  <a class="subHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/material/rapporter/internationell-utblick-loner-och-arbetskraftskostnader-juni-2005-_565749.html"> <h2>Internationell utblick - Löner och arbetskraftskostnader juni 2005 / International Outlook - Wages, Salaries, Labour Costs June 2005</h2> </a> 
  <div class="info-block"> 
   <p><a class="noHover" href="http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/medarbetare/krister-b-andersson_560480.html"><span class="entypo entypo-user"></span><span>Krister B Andersson</span></a></p> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

You can see, that the outer div is of class `subHover`, which you pick up in your code. Later you select any inside `a` that has an attribute `href`, but you do not force the class of that `a` to be also  `subHover`.

Why don't you just use CSS selectors? This should work:

```
String website = "http://www.svensktnaringsliv.se/english/publications/?start=" +maxPage;
Document docOne = Jsoup.connect(website).get();
Elements els = docOne.select("a.subHover");
for (Element el : els ){
  System.out.println(el);
}
```

I would recommend learning the power of CSS selectors, [as described in the JSoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).